# AdomdClient missing

Tags: c#, ssas, adomd.net

I would like to add AdomdClient Reference to a C# Project, but it is not in the reference list.
The Client is listed in the assembly Folder C:\Windows\assembly.

On the machine is SQL Server 2012 installed.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: ok. sorry the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it in your solution, and you know the location (as you indicated, in c:\windows\assembly), right click your References node in the solution explorer in Visual Studio, then click "Add Reference." Click the "Browse" button, find your DLL file, and click "Add" in the dialogue box. It should show up checked in your reference list. You should then be able to reference it in your C# file.

If you don't have the ADOMD client DLL file handy, download it from the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065). Click "install instructions" and look for "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 ADOMD.NET"

Comment: The view of c:\windows\assembly in the Explorer is an other view than in the open-dialog. I can't find it in the open-dialog.
Thanks for the link to the Freature Pack. I will try it.

Comment: Many Thanks. After install the Feature Pack i find the DLL.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\110

Answer (score 3):

You can also install it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient/).

Run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient
```

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Instead, tailor each of your answers to the specific question. If you have the necessary reputation points, you can [flag](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) or [vote-to-close](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) questions as duplicates, where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` is deprecated and should not be used according to the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient/) page.

The [following package worked](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient/) for me:

```
Install-Package Unofficial.Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient
```

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, I can find the reference for SQL Server 2008 at

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll
```

For SQL Server 2012, I would assume the version (directory "100") would be higher, probably "110". The location is a bit strange, as it is meant for Integration Services data flow components, but I just checked another computer having SQL Server 2008 installed, and it has the file at the same location.

Comment: That may be in that location because the SSIS components _use_ AdoMdClient, not because that's the primary location of it.

Comment: If you do a global search on your computer for `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll`, do you find it? Do you have Analysis Services installed on your computer? Or any client tool accessing Analysis Services?

Comment: Yes, MS SQL 2012 Standard is installed. I selected the Analys-Services during the installation. I created a Multidimensional Project with Visual Studio 2010 and commit it to the SQL Server. An all this works on the same PC.
The global search does't find the dll.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is at [here.](http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.com/2013/11/cant-find-microsoftanalysisservicesadom.html)

> 1)      To add Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll
>   Browse to  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll

2)    To add Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient
Browse to  C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\100\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll